# XQuery: create array of maps

Tags: xquery

I don't understand how to dynamically create an array of maps in Xquery which in the end should be serialised as JSON:

I can create a simple/static array of maps like this

```
let $array := [map{"id": "4711"}, map{"id": "4712"}]
```

I can add another map like this:

```
let $array := array:append($array, map {"id": "4713"})
```

using the following

```
return 
 serialize($array, 
        <output:serialization-parameters>
            <output:method>json</output:method>
        </output:serialization-parameters>)
```

results in `[{"id":"4711"},{"id":"4712"},{"id":"4713"}]` which is perfect JSON for me.

But I have an arbitrary number of maps to add to this array based on a sequence, like this:

```
let $mylist := ("4714", "4715")
```

What I'd like to have as result is this:

```
[{"id":"4711"},{"id":"4712"},{"id":"4713"},{"id":"4714"},{"id":"475"}]
```

I'm trying to achieve this by:

```
let $array := array:append($array, 
    for $n in $mylist
    return map {"id": $n}
)
```

But this returns as result:

```
[{"id":"4711"},{"id":"4712"},{"id":"4713"},[{"id":"4714"},{"id":"4715"}]]
```

So, obviously the for loop creates another array and appends that to the existing one. How do I avoid that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the following should do it:

```
let $mylist := ("4714", "4715")
return array{ $mylist ! map{'id': .} }
```

It's a bit unfortunate in my view that `array{}` is special-purpose syntax rather than just being a function.

You can also do it with

```
array:join( $mylist ! [map{'id': .}] )
```

Comment: thanks for your proposal! Unfortunately both solutions return the error  message: exerr:ERROR org.exist.xquery.XPathException: err:XPST0003 expecting COLON, found ','

Comment: after changing the comma to a colon, like this:
`return array{ $mylist ! map{'id': .} }` the error message is gone, but no values are returned

Comment: After fixing the typo, it works for me. How are you running it?

Comment: I have an eXist-db, using Oxygen Editor I created a xquery file and defined a transformation scenario for it (transformer is the exist-db).

Comment: ok, got it running now! couldn't say why it didn't work in the first place, but thank you so much for your help!